# Getting MYSQL_TCP_ADDR From within Docker container using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, docker

So I am having a dilemma. I made a Flask app that uses a mysql DB for storing username and passwords when people log into the app. My question is, is there a dynamic way to get the TCP Port address within my Python code it self? What I am currently doing is just hardcoding the path like so:

```
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'UserList'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = '172.17.0.3'
```

But what I would like is to make the host dynamic so if I ever build another mysql container, I won't have to manually change the IP every time. I know you can do this command,

```
env | grep MYSQL
MYSQL_PORT_5123_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.3
MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
MYSQL_PORT_5123_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.3:5123
MYSQL_PORT_5123_TCP_PROTO=tcp
MYSQL_ENV_GOSU_VERSION=1.7
MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT=3306
MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.3:3306
MYSQL_PORT_5123_TCP_PORT=5123
MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.18-1debian8
MYSQL_NAME=/site-metrics/mysql
MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PROTO=tcp
MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.3
MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7
MYSQL_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.3:3306
```

But is there a way to do this within my Python script so I do not have to fiddle with this every time? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add them to the same network and refer to them by dns.

Comment: @johnharris85 Could you explain this more in depth? I know what you mean, but I am not sure how I would go about implementing this if that makes sense.

Comment: Look up the `--link` parameter for `docker run` or use `links` section in docker-compose. That will create a host name you can contact the mysql container on.

Comment: `--link` is deprecated @Grimmy in favor of networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by running both containers on the same network. I'll assume a local network for now but overlay works in the same way.

```
$ docker network create my-network
$ docker run --name db --net my-network <other args...>
$ docker run --name web --net my-network <other args...>
```

Then in your app config:

```
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'db'
```

Because both containers are on the same network, they will be able to resolve each other via DNS (using their container names).

Edit: In fact an *even better* way of doing it would be with an env variable that you pass in. Then you have the best of both worlds. Something like:

```
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = os.getenv('DB_HOST', 'db')
```

The second argument to `os.getenv()` is a default value. So by default it will use `'db'` but if for whatever reason in your environment you need to change it or have a different Docker service name, you can just run the container with:

```
$ docker run --name other_db --net my-network <other args...>
$ docker run --name web --net my-network -e DB_HOST=other_db <other args...>
```

Then it would try to connect to `other_db:<port>` instead.

Comment: Okay cool! That makes a lot more sense, I found this way in the meantime, lmk if this is applicable or if your way is much better. I just do a "myhost = os.environ.get('MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR)" and then set the HOST to that var.

Comment: That will work, but my way is the 'best' way of doing it as you don't have any of that dependency inside the container. Just handling everything with networking / service mesh later if applicable. I believe those environment variables are only written when using `--link` as well, which is deprecated. Oh and the biggest issue, those are only written at startup, if your DB goes down and is restarted, Docker won't edit those env vars in your web container, so everything will break.